# Angular translate with accents

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using angular-translate and a JSON file utf-8 with the value:

```
"TAB_ES" : "Características"
```

I get the string "Caracter&#237;sticas" when I use:

```
<uib-tab heading="{{'TAB_ES'|translate}}"></uib-tab>
```

How I can print the value correctly?

Answer (score 4):

I resolve this with:

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitizeParameters');
```